# How to find a shared folder in my guest machine?

Tags: virtualbox, shared-folders

[image]

Inspect this image. See that I have put a folder on my local (host) machine as the shared folder named Downloads1 in my guest machine. This works, hooray!

Now I need to find it in my virtual (guest) ubuntu machine. How can I find this folder, named Downloads1?

Comment: Did you install the virtualbox guest additions on the virt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to mount the shared folder. It is all spelled out [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders). Basically you run this command in a terminal window:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=$UID,gid=$(id -g) share ~/host
```

In your case replace `share` with `Downloads1` and `~/host` with a path where you want the shared folder to reside.

There is much more information in the linked document.